# Dynamically Including Components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular application that has (so far) a plugin mechanism so that I can add and modify menu items at runtime. To do this, I have a service where plugins can register themselves, such as:

```
MenuService.addItem(
    "/main/foo",
    "bar",
    {
        title : "Bar",
        templateUrl : "foo/bar/templates/bar.html",
        controller : "BarController",
        controllerAs : "bar",
        visible : true,
        [...]
    }
);
```

and then I have a directive to retrieve and iterate over items add a given hierarchy level. Internally, this uses a $route to register routes, and a template can render the structure like this:

```
 <li menu-item path="/main">
     <a href="{{item.path}}">{{item.title}}</a>
     <ul ng-if="items.children.length>0">
         <li menu-item path="{{item.path}}">
         </li>
     </ul>
 </li>
```

this is all pretty simple and works fine. Now, I also want to include entire views in a similar way. Approximately like this:

```
<div include-components path="/main/foo">
</div>
```

I would like to iterate over the items registered at this path and either duplicate the node the directive is on or add child nodes with the right templates and controllers set. If there's only one item like the one above is registered, the resulting DOM should look like this:

```
<div 
    include-components 
    path="/main/foo" 
    ng-controller="BarController" 
    ng-include="...template.html">

    [included template+controller render here]

</div>
```

or (with child elements):

```
<div include-components path="/main/foo">
    [first registered template /w controller]
    [second registered template /w controller]
    [...]
</div>
```

My current attempt kind of looks like this:

```
angular.module("angular-plugin").directive(
    "includeComponents",
    function(MenuService,$route,$templateCache) {
        console.log($route);
        return {
            transclude: 'element',
            scope: {
                path : "@"
            },
            link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl,transclude) {
                var items = MenuService.get(scope.path);
                items.forEach(function(each){
                     [... what?]
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I tried a lot of different things inside that loop ... but I've not been able to make the template display, much less to get the controller in that item to initialize. I was looking at the source code of ngView, which should be doing something really similar... but I've not been able to get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I spent some more time looking at ngView ... and I figured out the directive below. This does work, pretty much. Is there anything missing? Do I have to do any cleanup afterwards?

```
angular.module("foobar").directive(
    "includeComponents",
    function(PluginMenuService,$route,$templateCache,$controller,$compile) {
        console.log($route);
        return {
            scope: {
                path : "@"
            },
            link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl,transclude) {
                var items = PluginMenuService.get(scope.path);
                if(items.length > 0) {
                    items.forEach(
                        function(each) {
                            templ = $templateCache.get(each.templateUrl);
                            var child = el.append(templ);
                            var controller = $controller(each.controller, {});
                            var link = $compile(child.contents());

                            childScope = scope.$new();

                            childScope[each.controllerAs] = controller;
                            childScope["component"] = each;
                            child.data('$ngControllerController', controller);

                            link(childScope);
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    });
```